# How to estimate potential path area (PPA) using {STPtrajectories} package in R

Tags: r, time, geospatial, spatial, temporal

I am using a package {STPtrajectories} for my research to estimate inhabitans's `potential path area (PPA)`, which is used in the terminology of spatio-temporal analysis, as an objective variable of an analysis which aims to validate if there is a significant difference of living sphere (or home range) between different type of inhabitants in a city.

However, I got quite large PPA than I expected following a tutorial which is introduced [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markvregel/STPtrajectories/master/vignettes/STP_Tracks.html).

As I am using person trip data which only contains start/end point and time of movement in one day, I converted it into 24 hours activity format and estimated PPA something like this:

```
## ---------- START OF CODE ---------- ##

## Load packages
library(sp)
library(spacetime)
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
library(xts)
library(rgeos)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)
library(STPtrajectories)

## Start time of activity
time <- as.POSIXct(c(
"2012-01-01 00:00:00",  # Sleeping
"2012-01-01 07:00:00",  # Start to leave for workplace
"2012-01-01 07:30:00",  # Arrive at workplace [change coordinates]
"2012-01-01 10:00:00",  # Start to leave for home
"2012-01-01 10:30:00",  # Arrive at home for houseshore [change coordinates]
"2012-01-01 17:30:00",  # Start to leave for another destination
"2012-01-01 17:45:00",  # Arrive at another destination  [change coordinates]
"2012-01-01 21:30:00",  # Start to leave for home
"2012-01-01 21:45:00"), # Arrive at home [change coordinates]
origin="1970-1-1",tz="Asia/Phnom_Penh")

## End time of activity
endtime <- as.POSIXct(c(
"2012-01-01 07:00:00",  # Sleeping and preparation to leave
"2012-01-01 07:30:00",  # Arrive at workplace
"2012-01-01 10:00:00",  # End time of work
"2012-01-01 10:30:00",  # Arrive at home
"2012-01-01 17:30:00",  # Houseshore and leave for another destination
"2012-01-01 17:45:00",  # Arrive at anther destination
"2012-01-01 21:30:00",  # Arrive at destination  [change coordinates]
"2012-01-01 21:45:00",  # Do private matter and leave for home
"2012-01-02 00:00:00"), # End of the day  [change coordinates],
origin="1970-1-1",tz="Asia/Phnom_Penh")

## X coordinates of activity
x <- c(
475465.6, # Home
475465.6, # Home (time to leave)
473548.0, # Workplace (time to start to work)
473548.0, # Workplace (time to leave for home)
475465.6, # Home (houseshore)
475465.6, # Home (time to leave for another destination)
484869.7, # Another place (private matter)
484869.7, # Another place (time to leave for home)
475465.6  # Home (night time until sleep)
)

## Y coordinates of activity
y <- c(
1272272,
1272272,
1279171,
1279171,
1272272,
1272272,
1270558,
1270558,
1272272
)

## Combine X and Y
xy <- cbind(x,y)

## Dummy data frame for spdf
dummy <-  data.frame(sp=rep(0,nrow(test)))

## Build spatial points data frame
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy,data=dummy,
            proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +north +zone=48 ellps=WGS84"))

## Dummy data frame for STIDF
dummy <-  data.frame(df=rep(0,nrow(test)))

## Activity time: this is canceled to implement
# a <- track@connections
# a$duration[a$speed!=0] <- 0
# atime <- a$duration

## Build STIDF class object
stidf <- STIDF(spdf,time,dummy,endtime)

#### Build track class object
track <- Track(stidf)
## Convert meters into kilometers
track@connections$distance <- track@connections$distance/1000
## Convert velocity m/s into km/h
track@connections$duration <- track@connections$duration/3600

#### Build STP_track class object
## Velocity to build STP_track class object
v <- track@connections$speed * 1.0 # No adjustment
v[v==0] <- 3.0 # Walk speed in kph
## BUild STP_track class object
stp <- STP_Track(track=track,vmax=v)

## Plot STP_track class object
xrange <- c(350000,605000)   # Manually set to see too large PAA
yrange <- c(1140000,1410000) # Manually set to see too large PAA
plot(stp,type="p",col="red",pch=16,cex=2,xlim=xrange,ylim=yrange,
     xlab="lon (meters)",ylab="y (meters)",main="Tragectories of xxx")

#### Estimate PPA
ppa <- PPA(stp)
plot(ppa,add=T)
ppa.area <- area(ppa)

## ---------- END OF CODE ---------- ##
```

This is current output from the codes:

[image]
Note:Administrative boundaries are shown only for your understanding

I expected that PPA will be estimated just around each red point of activity because velocity of each movement is just around 3-10 kph and its duration is about an hour or less than that, however estimated PPA covers almost the entire city as shown in the figure.

There are some basic issues/assumptions of the data frame:

1. Coordinates of activity
   Location of each activity is not coded in actual coordinates but represented by zone centroids which is built at the center of administrative boundaries.
2. Number and duration of activities
   It is assumed that inhabitants' movements are fixed only at the timing of movement, thus, in this data frame, his/her movements are fixed in 9 time when s/he (1)woke up, (2)left for work, (3)arrived at workplace, (4)left for home, (5)arrive at home, (6)left for another destination, (7)arrive at another destination, (8) left for home, (9) arrived at home. Thus, `[activity_time]`in `@connections` is not set.
   Thus, s/he should be able to move around beetween each activity.
   However, due to this format, some pairs of activities have no distance, such as activities between (1) and (2). I suppose it may not be an issue to estimate PPA.
3. No interpolation between activities
   Random trajectories are estimated in the example. However, I did not apply this operation for my data frame because it is not affordable to generates new points far from actual activity locations. However, it seems to affect the result of such huge PPA.
   For the information, when I reduced the number of split of data frame in the example (e.g., `n_points` is changed from 15 to 3), it still generated ellipsoid PPA which is still affordable, however it did not happen in my data frame.
4. Tricky behavior of the package

   - According to vignettes of `{STPtrajectories}`, `endTime` stamps of the track points and `activity_time` is used to prohibit the sample move during the activity. However, those two variables seem not to affect the result when I changed the setting.
   - `Speed` and `period` in `@connections` slot  
     Track class object originally stores distance as meter, period as minutes and speed as kph. As it seems not to be uniformed, I converted the distance into kilometer and period into hour after building track class object. However, it also does not affect the result of PPA estimation.

It is highly appreciated if you could give an advice for appropriate PPA estimation.

Comment: I could obtain appropriate PPA estimation result after try and error. Basically there is no need to change units of `duration`, `distance` and `vmax` in `connections` slot of space-time prism class object and you'll get appropriate PPA. `endTime` and `activity_time` do not affect the result.